# Running a reactjs front end and i notice that the reload icon get activated -- does that mean it is not a SPA?

Tags: reactjs

I was under the impression that for single page applications the reload did not occur. Can one determine from looking at the code and/or behavior whether an app is a SPA? For example the code uses (I think) a router -- does that imply that a reactjs app is a SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In non SPA when you click on a link it load new page which in chrome is shown by spinning circle on tab where title is written. In spa this happens only once when you visit website after that it doesn't show spinnig circle on url change as you navigate website.
Look at reddit website for spa and stack overflow website for non spa.